# Could someone explain this make file?

Tags: makefile

I found this makefile on this [site](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/).  They don't explain this example, so I was wondering if anybody new what was going on.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: The first lines as Chris points out are defining shorthands, the rest is a 'dependency graph'. When you change your source files the `make` system will start executing the rules bottom up to get to the final result, ultimately creating an up-to-date executable `hello` compiled.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
```

sets four variables to be constant strings.  For the rest of the makefile, wherever `$(CC)` appears (for example), it will be replaced by `g++`

```
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```

sets the variable OBJECTS to be the same as SOURCES, except wherever the pattern `.cpp` appears in a words of SOURCES, its replaced by `.o`

```
EXECUTABLE=hello
```

sets another constant string var

```
all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

The first actual rule in the makefile, This tells make that to build `all` it must first build everything in `$(SOURCES)` and `$(EXECUTABLE)`, and then do nothing.  Since this is first, it becomes the default target, so running `make` is equivalent to `make all`

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

Another rule: to create `$(EXECUTABLE)` (which expands to `hello`) it must first build everything in `$(OBJECTS)` (equivalent to `main.o hello.o factorial.o`) and then run the command `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@`

```
.cpp.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

A pattern rule: in order to build a file ending in `.o`, first rebuild/create/find the corresponding file ending in .cpp, and then run the command `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<`.

These last two rules contain the special variables `$@` and `$<` which are only valid in rule actions and expand to the target and first dependency respectively

So when you run `make`, it reads all this and then tries to build the default target (all).
Since it doesn't exist, it tries to build the files main.cpp, hello.cpp, factorial.cpp, and hello.  Since the first 3 (presumably) exist, it looks for rules/dependencies for them, but doesn't find any, so decides there's nothing to do for them.  If they didn't exist, make would give an error saying "no rule to make target 'main.cpp'"

In the case of "hello" it depends on main.o, hello.o and factorial.o, so it looks into them.  For main.o, the pattern rule says it depends on main.cpp, so if main.o doesn't exist or if main.cpp is newer, it will run the command `g++ -c -Wall -o main.o main.cpp`.  The same happens for hello.o and factorial.o.

Once those are done, if `hello` doesn't exist or is older than any of those .o files (which may have just changed, so are possibly pretty new), it will run that command to relink it.  Finally, it will run the empty command (doing nothing) to 'rebuild' all.

Comment: The only thing that I don't understand is why in the pattern rule it is necessary call again `-o $@`. Can you explain me this ? Thanks

Comment: @Kyrol: `-o` specifies the name of the file to write to.  On some compilers, the default output file may already be the same as the target, but respecifying doesn't hurt.

Comment: Isn't `.cpp.o:` a Suffix Rule and not a Pattern Rule?

Comment: @jdknight: technically yes, but suffix rules and pattern rules are really just two slightly different syntaxes for the same thing -- a rule that matches a target based on a filename pattern and figures out the dependencies based on that.

Comment: How can you use a rule like `%.c : %.o` with a different output folder?

Comment: @MarcusJ: you would use a rule like `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<`  That's part of why pattern rules were added -- tthey're more flexible that suffix rules.