# Makefile that builds source code in different directories

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, static-linking

I like the step by step explanation of this makefile

[Could someone explain this make file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098798/could-someone-explain-this-make-file)

As a recap, it is as follows

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $
```

Can someone explain how to modify this to work for source file that is in a different directory?

For example, say the directory structure is as follows

```
/src/hello/
/src/hello/main.cpp
/src/hello/hello.cpp
/src/hello/factorial.cpp
/src/hello/makefile   [THIS makefile]
/src/util/util.h
/src/util/util.cpp
```

What needs to be modified in the makefile in order for me to be able to do `#include "uti.h"` in say, `main.cpp`?

Btw I think I've read somewhere that I can use `VPATH` for this. Can someone elaborate?

EDIT - Someone asked me where I want `util.o` to go. I think the logical next question is - why not just build a static library?

I think once my project finishes, I will build a static library. But (correct me if I'm wrong), but static library is just an archive of a bunch of related `.o`s. I'm not sure what `.o`s are related yet. Do I want to `util.o`? Do I want a `math.o`? Do I want a `timeSeries.o`? Or do I want them as a single `.a`? I'm not sure yet. So in the meantime, let me just see all the individual `.o`s and have my `main` link to them.

Comment: You can add `-I` to `CFLAGS`: `CFLAGS=-c -Wall -I../util`, and modify `SOURCES=... ../util/util.cpp`

Comment: Where do you want `util.o` to go?

Comment: I guess `util.o` can either stay in the `util` directory or be in the `hello` directory. My preference would be for it to be in the `util` directory so that if later I have a `hello2` directory, it can find `util.o` and just link to it. But please correct me if what I'm saying doesn't sound like the right approach.